# How to do IntelliJ android gradle intra module dependencies?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm comfortable with maven, so gradle doesn't seem like it's a huge jump. But, I cannot figure out how to make intra module dependencies work.

In IntelliJ I created 4 modules like this:

```
SharedLib1
FooApp
    FooAppLib
    FooAppMain
```

The dependencies I want are:

```
FooAppMain -> FooAppLib
FooAppLib -> SharedLib1
```

In maven all I'd need to do is refer to other things by their group, artifactid, and version. However, none of the build.gradle files generated contain anything that looks like a group or artifactid, so I don't know how to refer modules to each other.

Something like this seems appropriate for the FooAppMain build.gradle file:

```
compile project(":FooAppLib")
```

However, that just doesn't work. There are other dependencies like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
```

But again, I don't know where to put the group and artifactid values in the build.gradle so I can refer to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a settings.gradle file in the project root and configure the lib project path there.

```
include ':app', ':FooAppLib'


project(':FooAppLib').projectDir = file('../yourLibProjectRoot/app')
```

And then in your build.gradle file, add the dependency to this project

```
compile project(":FooAppLib")
```

Comment: I had to use the full path in the file() rather than a relative path, but after making that change it's working. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to use the full path. Please notice that the relative path is relative to the setting.gradle file, not the build.gradle file.